# Painting over metallic paint

Tags: painting

I want to paint over a Ralph Lauren Metallic Silver paint. When we applied it we rolled it on and then took a wide wallpaper brush to create an "industrial sheet metal" look for our son's motorcycle room. Now he has moved out and we want to lighten the room up but now I have this texture and metallic paint. Any suggestions on best way to cover? Thanks

Comment: If you want to cover the texture also.  That falls in the rubric of "paint prep".   Unfortunately these days they make painting so easy that paint prep seems hard by comparison, and folks aren't ready for the amount of work it can be.